# ImportError: No module named winreg - Odoo10

Tags: python, odoo

I installed Odoo 10 CE on windows 7. In one custom module, I use `import winreg` but it gives me the error: ImportError: No module named winreg

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using python 2 try: `import _winreg as winreg`